# Do pumps and motors also need flyback diodes?

Tags: diodes, flyback, solenoid, fluid-pump

So my question is simple, we know that its good practice to use flyback diodes in solenoid valves and relays, but do pumps and motors also need them as they also have coils?

Comment: The answer is not simple because it depends on which pumps and motors you talk about and how do you drive them.

Comment: Something like a DC 12 V and DC 6V

Comment: The voltage itself does not define the need for diodes.

Comment: Perhaps [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/322120) will help.

Comment: Pumps, solenoids and motors don't necessarily need diodes or any form of snubber. The diode isn't there because of the needs of the inductive part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flyback diodes are also needed for DC motors and pumps.
For AC motors we also need snubbers to limit the voltage transient but usually made of resistor in series with a capacitor.

Comment: Is this also true  for BLDC and stepper motors?

Comment: The BLDC motor is an AC motor and a driver circuit bundled. The driver circuit contains all the protective gear in order to at all work. If you want to drive the BLDC driver externally, then no, you don't need flybacks. The whole bundle shows no inductance and does not "fly back".

Answer (score 2):

AC circuitry has the benefit of short half-cycles
of power, separated by zero crossings.   So, an arc
on switch contacts is usually short and nondestructive.

Diode clamps are common for suppressing
arcing with DC excited coils.

Several other treatments are possible: old house switches
were long-span snap action (increases the air gap
quickly so the spark extinguishes), newer ones  have
special long-lasting alloys for the contact points,
and occasionally a snubber network (usually a capacitor
and resistor) is used, if only to keep radio hash from
developing.

The common use of MOV devices also suppresses surges
and is compatible with AC  power; a diode type device,
the V stands for 'varistor', meaning its resistance
is high unless applied voltage peaks.

A diode (or back-to-back diode pair) can sometimes be
used, but... the other solutions to contact arcing are more common, and work for AC powered circuitry.