# Using a DC motor as a generator as well as a motor with PWM

Tags: mosfet, dc-motor, raspberry-pi

Hi ladies and gentlemen,

I am new to Mosfets and I could use some help!

I want to make a circuit where a DC motor is used as a motor and as a generator.
I would like to use PWM to control in motor mode and in generator mode using N-channel Mosfets.

I have made the following circuit:
[image: Circuit with two mosfets for generator and motor control]

This circuit is obviously shorted out, but I cannot figure out how to have both functionalities while not being short-circuited.

When the motor is used as a generator, the left wire of the motor is negative and right one positive in the picture (for the bottom mosfet).

I have tested the circuits separately as motor and as generator and they work, just not together.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!
Here is a link to the diagram: https://crcit.net/c/7e69a5c214f649c3b7b92a090ad6ff37

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to use a diode in combination with a N-channel MOSFET?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/575945/is-it-possible-to-use-a-diode-in-combination-with-a-n-channel-mosfet)

Comment: What does the 22 ohm resistor do?

Comment: The 22 ohm resistor is a load for the generator. With PWM, the load can be 'lowered' at will. This is handy for my experimental setup because I want to control the force that the generator applies.

Comment: *I have tested the circuits separately as motor and as generator and they work, just not together*.  Could you clarify what you mean by together?

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat If I only connect the top circuit, so +3V -> Mosfet -> Motor -> 0V, then the motor can be controlled with PWM. If I only connect the bottom circuit, so Motor- -> mosfet -> resistor -> motor+, then the motor can be used as PWM controlled generator and it works well. But if I try to put the two circuits together, as I have done in the picture, then there is a short circuit. But I cannot seem to make a configuration where the mosfets are grounded at the source without having a short-circuit.

Comment: You have to control the circuits.  You just cannot connect both and expect them to work.  You need MOSFETs to say now you are a generator.  Now motor.

Comment: You need to follow Andy's advice.

Answer (score 1):

> *This circuit is obviously shorted out, but I cannot figure out how
> make it not short-circuited.*

Then un-short it like this: -

[image]

However, if you want it to properly work as a motor and a generator then use a H bridge circuit like this: -

[image]

Taken from [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yk7Z6NxMQmY) that might help your understanding.

When used as a generator, the diodes across the MOSFETs return electrical power from the mechanically driven motor back to the supply rails. I wouldn't roll my own H bridge; I'd use an OTS commercial chip.

Comment: I tried the top scheme but it does not work, you need to connect the source of the Mosfet to the ground for it to work right?

Comment: @PurpleTurtle I'm just pointing out where the short is and then pointing you in a sensible direction regarding turning a motor into a generator by using a H bridge. I'm not about to go through your highly flawed circuit that is upside down and try and figure out how to get from failure to success when the H bridge is a standard way to do this.

Comment: Well your answer made it seem like it would work if one just removes the short. But thanks anyway :).

Comment: @PurpleTurtle your question appeared to be about how to figure out where the short is. There is a skill to writing a decent question.

Comment: ah I see, I have formulated it differently, hopefully people will understand now.

Comment: It makes no difference @PurpleTurtle - nobody is going to lead you down the path of fixing your flawed circuit when the clearly superior approach beckons. If you are hoping to get a blow-by-blow, verse-by-verse conversion from your broken circuit to a new and realistic circuit then you are not recognizing what this Q and A site is all about. You ask a question and someone (me in this example) provides an answer. An evolutionary training school is not what this site is about.

Comment: if you are just going to be salty, then please go be salty somewhere else. Your solution of an H bridge is to drive a motor forwards and backwards is not the same as using a motor as a generator. I get it you don't want to answer this, then don't, but don't go making snarky comments to someone who is genuinely interested to learn.

Comment: You have a lot to learn.